# Can't query for multiple posts with likes count

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to query Graph API for a set of posts (with ids of them). Let's assume i've got an array {firstId, secondId ...}. One way I've tried is:

```
v2.2/?ids=firstId,secondId...
```

Which works good as long as I don't want to get the likes/comments count summary through adding any "fields" param.

```
?fields=likes.limit(1).summary(true),comments.limit(1).summary(true)
```

Any ideas on how to merge ids with fields params in one request?

Comment: Can you show how you did it for one id?

Comment: Basically what you’re asking is how to put more than one query string parameter into an URL … which is of course done by separating them with an ampersand, `?foo=bar&baz=thisisverybasicknowledgedude`

Comment: @phwd `v2.2/post_id/?fields=id,picture,likes.limit(1).summary(true)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, CBroe for pointing out that 'basically what i was asking was how to put more than one query string parameter into an URL which is of course done by separating them with an ampersand'. After combining my parameters i got working query:

```
v2.2/?ids=firstId,secondId&fields=id,picture,likes.limit(1).summary(true)
```

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful.

Comment: @gustavohenke, This is not just a thank you. [ches](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4117651/ches) created a new answer based on the information [CBroe](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe) provided in comments on the question. While this might have been more clear with a statement in the answer like "Thanks to the comment made by CBroe, I was able to solve the problem with the following code:", providing attribution for the information that lead to the solution is quite appropriate.

Comment: @Makyen should actually be a community wiki in this case

Comment: @gustavohenke, A community wiki answer is a reasonable course.  However, from what I recall of the discussions on meta regarding transitioning a comment to an answer, the opinions about doing so vs. posting an answer authored by another person are a bit mixed.

Comment: @ches, Please [edit] in an explanation of why/how this code answers the question. People reading it should not need to go searching for a comment to find out why this answer is valid. Code-only answers are discouraged, because they are not as easy to learn from as code with an explanation. Without an explanation it takes considerably more time and effort to understand what was being done, if the code answers the question, etc. The explanation is important both for people attempting to learn from the answer and those evaluating the answer to see if it is valid, or worth up voting.

Answer (score 1):

Add your query after placing the list of IDs

Example,

`?ids=80329313253_10153216064543254,80329313253_10153211628853254&fields=likes.limit(1).summary(true),comments.limit(1).summary(true)`

```
{
  "80329313253_10153216064543254": {
    "id": "80329313253_10153216064543254", 
    "created_time": "2015-02-26T20:41:53+0000", 
    "likes": {
      "data": [
        {
          "id": "1463487230582100", 
          "name": "Anchidtha Lomthampinij"
        }
      ], 
      "paging": {
        "cursors": {
          "after": "MTQ2MzQ4NzIzMDU4MjEwMA==", 
          "before": "MTQ2MzQ4NzIzMDU4MjEwMA=="
        }, 
        "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/80329313253_10153216064543254/likes?limit=1&summary=true&after=MTQ2MzQ4NzIzMDU4MjEwMA=="
      }, 
      "summary": {
        "total_count": 318822
      }
    }, 
    "comments": {
      "data": [
        {
          "id": "10153216063838254_10153216079943254", 
          "from": {
            "id": "704159799640259", 
            "name": "Akshatha Bhat"
          }, 
          "message": "If I owned you, you'd never have to dream about treats because I would give you them all the time Boo!", 
          "can_remove": false, 
          "created_time": "2015-02-26T20:47:39+0000", 
          "like_count": 193, 
          "user_likes": false
        }
      ], 
      "paging": {
        "cursors": {
          "after": "Mjg3OQ==", 
          "before": "Mjg3OQ=="
        }, 
        "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/80329313253_10153216064543254/comments?limit=1&summary=true&after=Mjg3OQ=="
      }, 
      "summary": {
        "order": "ranked", 
        "total_count": 2879
      }
    }
  }, 
  "80329313253_10153211628853254": {
    "id": "80329313253_10153211628853254", 
    "created_time": "2015-02-24T20:15:34+0000", 
    "likes": {
      "data": [
        {
          "id": "744777938907452", 
          "name": "Faya Gurbanli"
        }
      ], 
      "paging": {
        "cursors": {
          "after": "NzQ0Nzc3OTM4OTA3NDUy", 
          "before": "NzQ0Nzc3OTM4OTA3NDUy"
        }, 
        "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/80329313253_10153211628853254/likes?limit=1&summary=true&after=NzQ0Nzc3OTM4OTA3NDUy"
      }, 
      "summary": {
        "total_count": 407425
      }
    }, 
    "comments": {
      "data": [
        {
          "id": "10153211628843254_10153211643418254", 
          "from": {
            "id": "398118870328160", 
            "name": "Nicole Newell"
          }, 
          "message": "This is the most precious pup I've ever seen. Can we clone him?", 
          "can_remove": false, 
          "created_time": "2015-02-24T20:21:32+0000", 
          "like_count": 385, 
          "user_likes": false
        }
      ], 
      "paging": {
        "cursors": {
          "after": "Mzk5Nw==", 
          "before": "Mzk5Nw=="
        }, 
        "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/80329313253_10153211628853254/comments?limit=1&summary=true&after=Mzk5Nw=="
      }, 
      "summary": {
        "order": "ranked", 
        "total_count": 3997
      }
    }
  }
}
```